# Hom Functor Preserves Direct Products

Tags: homological-algebra, direct-product

I'm looking at a statement in Rotman's 'Introduction to Homological Algebra' which I'm having a problem with:

> **Theorem 2.30.i**: There is a $Z(R)$-isomorphism $$\varphi : \text{Hom}_R \bigg( A, \prod_{i \in I} B_i \bigg) \to \prod_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R (A, B_i)$$ with $\varphi : f \mapsto (p_if)$, where the $p_i$ are the projection of the direct product $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} B_i$. If $R$ is commutative, then $\varphi$ is an $R$-isomorphism.

**Q1**: I don't understand why we need to restrict it to a $Z(R)$-map?

**Q2**: It' simply an $R$-map, isn't it? which makes the last line in the statment redundant?

In his proof, he says the following:

> To see that $\varphi$ is a $Z(R)$-map, note, for each $i$ and each $r \in Z(R)$, that $p_i r f = r p_i f$; therefore, $$\varphi : rf \mapsto (p_i r f) = (rp_i f) = r(p_if) = r \varphi(f).$$

But I don't see how he's using anything other than the fact that $p_i$ is an $R$-map which allows us to pull out the scalar.

**Q3**: Am I missing something here? Or did he add an unnecessary hypothesis?

Comment: this is true by abstract nonsense isn't it?

Comment: @Chilango, I don't understand? Why did Rotman restrict the map to be a $Z(R)$-isomorphism when a more general fact is true: that it's an $R$-isomorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $A$ and the $B_i$ are left $R$-modules; the following also applies if they're right $R$-modules.  Then, in the theorem you quoted, the Hom-sets have the structure of $Z(R)$-modules, but they are not, in general, $R$-modules, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $R$-isomorphisms between them.

Comment: That was the part I was missing. Thanks! I would upvote you, but I don't have 15 points yet.